# how to add wordpress theme in page which take template of external php file

Tags: wordpress

I want to make php file **"demo.php"** in geany editor and then I want to add that page in my website.To do this task I have add **"demo.php"** in folder **"wordpress/wp-content/themes/my_wesite_theme"** ,after that my wordpress show that file as template ***"demo"*** , up to this its  ok.  
      After that  i want to add new page ***"new-page-of-site"*** in wordpress which take template of ***"demo"*** which is my php file template ,after selection of that template when i view ***"new-page-of-site"*** in browser it show only output of that page without wordpress theme ,so how can I include wordpress theme in that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple process and is very easy to do.

First of all, you need to name the template correctly. This just means adding the prefix `page-` before the name of the template. Like so:

```
page-demo.php
```

Next, you have to add a tiny bit of code to the top of the template page just so that WordPress will know what the template is called.

Open up the new `page-demo.php` that you have created, and add this code to the top:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Demo
*/
// names the template
get_header(); // gets the header detail
?>
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
            //
            // Post Content here
            //
        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
<?php
get_footer(); // gets the footer detail
?>
```

I've added some code for the actual page but you'll want to change it up to fit your actual page layout.

When you get into the WordPress admin area for adding new pages, on the right hand side below the save button, you should have an area for changing the template, just choose the new option, save and then you should be able to view the page with the new template.

Comment: Thanks for giving response ,whats you are telling I have done that and it working well but I also want to include  image and all feature of website i.e theme,image etc in that page-demo.php

Comment: You just need to use the same code as what you have on the normal `page.php` template. See amended code above

Comment: Thanks Stewartside for giving your quick and appropriate response,now by using above code  I am able to get my page, in a manner what I want